# Trying to fix an error that wont let me start programming the rest of it

Tags: c++, class, templates, typename

I am getting an error in this project with classes I'm working on. The error is

> [Error] invalid use of template-name 'SimpleListContainer' without an argument list

```
//Application.cpp
#include <iostream>
#include "SimpleListContainer.cpp"
 using namespace std;
 int main()
   {
     SimpleListContainer obj1;
   }
```

This is the other file as it stands

```
    //#pragma once

#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

template <typename T>
class SimpleListContainer {

private:
    int size;
    const static int capacity = 5;
    T data[capacity];

public:
    SimpleListContainer();//which will add an item of type T to our array and return true, or return false if array already full
//  bool insert(T);//which will return true / false depending on if value T is present in array
//  bool search(T);//which will return the number of items currently stored(different from capacity which is fixed)
    int length();//which returns true if list is empty(size 0) or else false
    bool empty();//which prints all the data stored, line by line for each element in the array
    void print();//which clears the list by resetting size to 0
    void clear();//which deletes all instances of T found in the list and compresses the list via a simple algorithm
//  void remove(T);

};

SimpleListContainer::SimpleListContainer()
{
    size = 0;
}
```

I just need to know what I am doing wrong. This is my first time using Template in a program so I don't understand it at all and the online sources I've found did not fix the problem I am having.

Comment: Your template needs one parameter, a type.  What type should be used when instantiating the template?  How do you tell the compiler that?  (Check your notes and/or C++ book.)

Comment: Hint: How would you declare a vector of ints?

Comment: OT, but: `#include "SimpleListContainer.cpp"` Uuh! It's not directly forbidden to include cpp files but I warmly would recommend not to do so. The (very) usual convention is: compile cpp files on its own - `#include` only header files. If a project involves multiple cpp files - you have to link the corresponding produced object files together. (Therefore, templates are usually written as header only source files.)

Comment: Yes, it's normally a bad idea to include a *.cpp file. But template definitions must be included to be used. So the typical pattern would be to name the file SimpleListContainer.hpp, not SimpleListContainer.cpp. (Don't forget the multiple include guard.)

Answer (score 0):

> I just need to know what I am doing wrong.

You're not passing the type parameter when instantiating a class template.

A class template like so:

```
template<typename T>
class MyTemplate { public: T t; };
```

Needs the `T` filled in when it's used:

```
int main () {
    MyTemplate<int> o { 42 };
    std::cout << o.t;
}
```

You should go back to your C++ book and re-read the templates chapter.

Answer (score 0):

there's an error regarding how you separately define template class functions.
instead of

```
SimpleListContainer::SimpleListContainer()
{
```

you need to write:

```
template<typename T>
SimpleListContainer<T>::SimpleListContainer()
{
```